# Magento2 Cart Issues on Custom template

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, onepage-checkout

We are creating a custom template and have a couple of issues with onepage cart checkout

1. When adding to cart, MiniCart does not update with cart item number
2. When go to checkout, http://[url]/checkout the checkout-loader doesnt disappear and keeps spinning so cannot go any further

Are there any configurations or coding that need to be applied? We have kept to most of the Magento template files and updated the css/less files

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. The conflict was in the custom templates require-config.js. I removed this and KO template rendering was being activated again